# cast content of array into arithmetic type in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, access-violation, dereference

I'm facing weird behavior with casting (or more even dereferencing) single items from array into a single arithmetic type.

Heres a reduced test case:

```
void test1()
{
    unsigned char test[10] = {0};
    unsigned long i=0xffffffff;

    *((unsigned long *)(&test[3])) = i;


    int it;

    for ( it = 0 ; it < 10 ; it++ )

    {
        printf("%02x ", test[it]);

    }
}
void test2()
{
    unsigned char test[10] = {0};
    unsigned char test2[10] = {0};
    test[2]=0xFF;
    test[3]=0xFF;

    *((unsigned short *)(&test2[1])) = *((unsigned short *)(&test[2]));


    int it;

    for ( it = 0 ; it < 10 ; it++ )

    {
        printf("%02x ", test2[it]);

    }
}
```

In detail it is mainly this expression:

```
    *((unsigned short *)(&test2[1]))
```

I'm getting access violations on some other platforms (mainly embedded platforms like PIC24).

So my question is: is this C conformant? I can't find anything within C-standard but maybe I'm only blind.

Do you know any alternatives doing this operation without such cast (looping byte-to-byte copy/unrolling etc. is not meant!) and where I don't need to know the current byte order of the platform?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
 *((unsigned short *)(&test2[1]))
```

This is undefined behavior, you are violating alignment and aliasing rules. Don't do it.

Your `test2` object is an array of `unsigned char` and through the cast you are accessing its elements as `unsigned short` objects. There is no guarantee that `unsigned char` alignment requirement is the same as `unsigned short` alignment requirement.

In the C standard you can find information on alignment in 6.3.2.3p7 (C99) and on aliasing rules in 6.5p7.

A good rule of thumb is to always be very wary in presence of casts in the left side of the `=` operator.

Comment: Wary, sure, but sometimes you really do need to do weird stuff, and it's a good thing that C allows you to do it. Though I usually prefer `union`s for that sort of thing, it's a much cleaner solution than pointer casts.

Answer (score 3):

The line `*((unsigned long *)(&test[3])) = i;` has undefined behavior. it depends on sizeof(long) and the endianness of your machine.
In general, you should not cast between different pointer types (except of `void*`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is almost certainly that you're doing unaligned access.  If chars are 1 byte and shorts are 2 (which is likely), then you're doing a write-short operation on an odd number.  This is not always supported and is why you're most likely getting an access violation.  If you really want to do this (which you probably don't), you could pad the char array by making it one char longer at the front and then just not use that first char (treat the array as 1-indexed rather than 0-indexed) and that would probably work on the platforms where this doesn't, but even that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem. But you can fix that with `#pragma pack`, the compiler will align the `char`s on 2-byte boundaries.

Comment: @cha0site: I think `#pragma pack` only has an effect on struct element packing - it's not applicable in this case, where we have an array

Comment: @PaulR: Seems you're right. But the [__attribute__ aligned](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) GCC extension does allow you to align arrays.

Comment: @cha0site: yes, but the aligned attribute only applies to the *start* of the array (i.e. the first element). If you try to access the third element of a char array as if it were a wider type such as int then this will *always* be misaligned, which may or may not result in a hardware exception.

Comment: @PaulR: You sure? The docs describe this as a sugary alternative to `union { int i; double d; } x[ARRAY_SIZE];`, which I'm pretty sure would align each element of the array to `sizeof(double)` boundaries.

Comment: If it aligned each element of the array, though, this would prevent his original purpose, though, which appears to be to overwrite two array elements with one statement (don't ask me why).

Comment: @cha0site: yes, it's only a base alignment for a given variable - it doesn't add padding between elements or anything like that - try it